# How to repeat a list of functions in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to have an infinite list of functions that cycles through some pattern. For example: `[(+), (-), (+), (-), ...]`

If I do something like

```
fmap repeat [(+), (-)]
```

then I get nested lists `[[a -> a -> a]]`. What's the best way to get a single infinite list of functions following a pattern like this?

Comment: You can use `concat (repeat [(+), (-)])`. Don't `fmap repeat`, that would get you multiple infinite lists that you would have to merge.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I could apply repeat to the contents of the list to avoid the nesting, but I realize why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are looking for is [**`cycle :: [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle):

```
cycle [(+),(-)]
```

The type of this expression is:

```
Prelude> :t cycle [(+),(-)]
cycle [(+),(-)] :: Num a => [a -> a -> a]
```

`cycle` takes a list `[a]` and produces a list where the given list is repeated over and over again. So `cycle [1,2,3]` produces `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,...]`